# I created 6 sprites with the same size in Illustrator, but they are given different sizes when sliced by the sprite editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, adobe-illustrator

I have tried anything but nothing works, so I came here to seek help.
I created an alien spaceship that has some lighting sources spread over it. I am just changing the lighting color between sprites, so it will create an animation.
So I put all my sprites in the same document, aligned them with equal spacing and height (based on their centers) but when I slice them with the sprite editor, each one is given a different width, so the spaceship moves a little bit to the left and then to the right between frames.
Is this a problem that related to the vector artwork of Illustrator? What can I do? [The PNG version of the artwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or0Lb.png)

Comment: I guess it could be because the vector sizes aren't rounded with pixel sizes. What much sizes of your sprites in pixels?

Comment: After resizing to 72 dpi (507 x 281 px) it look like this: https://imgur.com/a/fDbgjaI